# Does being a Fey creature type offer any advantages?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, races, racial-traits

In the book Mordenkainen Presents: Monsters of the Multiverse (MPMM), many creatures are classed as Fey, some that were not classed as fey now are, namely the Changeling.

However with things like Bugbear, Fairy, Eladrin - fey has some form of clarification.

Bugbear: You have advantage on saving throws you make to avoid or end the charmed condition on yourself. Fey Ancestry
Eladrin is very much the same.

Yet for creatures (like the Changeling) it simply says "you are Fey" - is that meant to come with something? In the same book some creatures that have some fey in them have magical resistances.

The blurb in the book & on D&DNbeyond offer up nothing to help ascertain if being Fey offers any additional racial perks. Or have Wizards gone mad with the Fey?